# Authentication from external tools with TFS Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, authentication, tfs

We've been using TFS (on premise) for version control for a long time and we recently moved our source code to a git repository in TFS. The Git functionality inside Visual Studio works great for everyone but some of our users have authentication problems working with Git in external tools from the command line or Git Extensions.
They are prompted for username and password every time a command is issued and then an error message is shown. I don't have the exact error message right now but it's something like "user information could not be retrieved".

Basic authentication is enabled in IIS on the TFS server and if we disable Windows authentication the external tools work ok for all users. But this causes problems with other tools that access our TFS server and require windows authentication. It's also a minor pain to require a log in in the web browser every time you access our TFS website.

The strange thing is that it works great for most user but a few have this problem. We all have the same version of Visual Studio (2015 update 1) and the same version of all Git tools. All users are on premise logged in to the same domain.

Comment: Am I correct that you're using alternate credentials? You're not using personal access tokens? (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate)

Comment: This is an on-premise TFS server, none of those options are available

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.0.0)? Please ensure that GCM is set as default by running `git config credential.helper manager`. Finally, if you haven't already done so it may be best to use your UPN as the username.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution was to just hit enter and leave username and password empty when prompted. After that it started working and the external tools no longer prompts for credentials.